# How could I choose extra keyboard layouts on Ubuntu Studio 18.04?

Tags: keyboard-layout, ubuntu-studio

I just a few days ago installed Ubuntu Studio. Before that I had used Ubuntu 18.04. 
That required customization Gnome program with a switch on features of extra layouts, but on Ubuntu Studio this program does not work. 
I think because of that Ubuntu Studio does not use the Gnome display manager as a basic. I don't want to install Gnome at all. 
Is there any choice to use extra layouts? (specially Old Hungarian)
Thanks.

Comment: Yes there is. Ubuntu Studio uses the Xfce desktop, right? I would be surprised it that desktop didn't offer a similar way to add and switch keyboard layouts as Ubuntu does. I don't use Xfce, though, so I'm not able to provide any details.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem myself.
Must install fcitx input method, logout, starting configurator of fcitx. After that layouts can be set with fcitx configuration only.